# How to Identify Actor Where Interface is doing the usecae

Tags: uml, system, modeling, actor

i am modeling a system of ware house management system(Assignment).In this system Most of the things are  done by automated crane. ok, being specific crane will read the barcode on it, its aso called licence plate. so, read licence plate is a USE CASE but who is the ACTOR here? Can Crane be the ACTOR or who else. Help is really Appreciated...

Comment: IMO. Definitely yes. You crane is a device which acts as an Actor to your whole system, or to an specific functionality (subsystem) of it.

Answer (score 1):

In fact it strongly depends of what you want to express.

UseCase are behavior of our system exposed outside.

So if you want to model "read licence plate" as a UseCase used by a crane, this implies that the crane is an Actor outside of your system.
If you want to model that the crane is a part of your system so the fact that our crane can read a licence plate you can not model it as a Usecase.

Hoping it helps.

Regards,